# Elegant way to negate a numeric value based on a boolean value

Tags: c#

I have a decimal variable that I would like to negate if a boolean variable is true. Can anyone think of a more elegant way to do it than this:

```
decimal amount = 500m;
bool negate = true;

amount *= (negate ? -1 : 1);
```

I'm thinking something along the lines of bitwise operators or a strictly mathematical implementation.

Comment: elegant enough I think. Bitwise on floating point numbers and mathematical implementation would make the code unnecessarily complicated. It would be interesting to know the elegant solution though.

Comment: the most elegant solution is the more readable, yet still reasonable efficient one.  Ergo, see Reed's answer.

Comment: @Shamim: This is a `decimal`, not a floating-point value.

Comment: @Chad: I was aware of Reed's solution :). I was thinking the  OP wanted something fancy, like those bit operators on http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html.

Comment: The real problem here is how many people think hacks are elegant.  There is nothing I hate more then reading someone else's "elegant" code that i have to squint at because they think they are being fancy.  In reality, they are taking years off my life.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Personally, I would just use an if statement, since I feel that it's the most clear in terms of intent:

```
decimal amount = 500m;
bool negate = true;

// ...

if (negate)
    amount *= -1;
```

This is really not any extra typing (it's actually shorter!), and more clear in my opinion.

Comment: @Tigran: Simple and clear == elegant.  Besides, this is most likely more efficient, too....

Comment: @Tigran, I disagree. Reed's solution is obvious. I feel the asker is looking for something more obscure. Obscurity is not elegance.

Comment: Keep It Simple, Stupid (KISS)

Comment: @Anthony I understand, only think that saying "elegant", for me at least, means kind of "cool". I usually never choose "cool" solution, but question searches for that one, BY ME.

Comment: @Tigran: "elegant" and "cool" are not synonyms. In fact, many times the "cool" solution (meaning that it's interesting or unexpected) is often the least elegant, since it's very often obtuse.

Comment: "Cool" is USUALLY (but not always) a solution when you sit in front with WTF face and try to understand "what that guy wrote here" :)

Comment: i've thought about the definition of "elegant" a number of times and often conclude it means realizing when a number of less than obviously related things, like side effects, produce a cancelling effect on the total complexity of the system they take part in...

Comment: @Tigran: Agreed; and that's not usually an "elegant" solution.

Comment: @Gabriel: I'd only change that by saying that an elegant solution is sometimes not an *obvious* solution (though it can be), but that it's always obvious *why* it's the solution when presented.

Comment: Admitted, this was a very subjectively named topic. Thanks to all for pointing out the fine balance between elegance and readability. What I should've asked for was a "clever" way of doing it. I think your code sample is the most straight forward, but as Tigran said, not so elegant (again: subjective). I think the single line approaches are easy enough for any non-novice to read while eliminating an extra line which, for me, makes traversing code more easy (especially when scrolling and searching through code). Marked as answer because you're all absolutely right, elegance != coolness.

Answer (score 2):

Use the decimal unary negation operator (as you are sort of already doing):

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        bool negate = true;
        decimal test = 500M;
        Console.WriteLine(negate == true ? -test : test);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-500
```

Frankly, this is much clearer and better than multiplying by -1 in that strange way.

Comment: Hey guise! What's going on in here?

Comment: It is clearer, I agree. I had an unexplained, traumatic experience with the unary negation operator in the past so I avoid using it now. I can't remember the details but it was throwing an exception when I would apply it to a decimal variable.

Comment: I tried to mark both your answer and the other as "the answer" but I guess there can only be one. I settled on the other because I feel the discussion below it brings valuable points to the table. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another shot across the math wizards?

How about adjusting your existing solution to be slightly more readable, but still make use of the statement?true:false shortcut?

Your solution was:

```
amount *= (negate ? -1 : 1);
```

Maybe refactor that to

```
amount = (negate ? amount*-1 : amount);
```

To add even more readability to your code, you might make a reusable class that handles that kind of stuff for you:

```
public static class MathHelpers()
{
  // Negates the result if shouldNegate is true, otherwise returns the same result
  public static decimal Negate(decimal value, bool shouldNegate)
  {
    // In this black-box solution you can use "fancier" shortcuts
    return value *= negate ? -1 : 1;
  }
}
```

And in your other code, you now have a very readable function to use...

```
decimal amount = 500m;
bool negate = true;
amount = MathHelper.Negate(amount, negate);
```

All in all, though I agree that elegance and readability live in the same cart, not different ones:

```
if (condition)
  output *= -1;
```

is more readable than

```
value *= condition ? -1 : 1;
```

Comment: I see where you're going with the idea of a function, however, I think it would be the least readable solution of all. Now you've got a function with a name that doesn't imply the conditionality in its behavior and you'd have to go to it to see what it does, then come back to continue reading. For that reason, I usually avoid writing functions that contain only a few simple lines. I think your last example is a trade off between conciseness and code simplicity. In this case, less lines of code would be the more readable for me personally. Great points to think through, thank you.

Comment: You are right, that the function name is poorly worded. Given a proper function name, it could be very readable. I'm also a fan of extension methods, as hungryMind listed.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static decimal Negate(this decimal value, bool isNegate){
    if(isNegate) return value * -1;
    return value;
}
```

Make extension method on decimal. Easy to use.

call like `amount.Negate(negate)`

Comment: wat's wrong ??? why downvote? Please leave comments if you downvote so that we know what we was wrong and rectify further

Comment: Thanks for your reply. See my response to EtherDragon for my thoughts on a method.

Answer (score 1):

This already exists, since Framework 1.1:

System.Decimal.Negate method

[public static decimal Negate(
    decimal d
)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.negate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Sample Usage:

```
decimal amount = 500m;
bool negate = true;

if(negate)
    amount = decimal.Negate(amount);
// amount now holds -500
// Use amount
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `negate` flag is based on some numeric value you can use `Math.Sign`, that's the most "mathematical" way I can think of.

```
double negationValue = -45.0;
amount *= Math.Sign(negationValue);
```

or in boolean case just (not really elegant):

```
amount *= Math.Sign(0.5 - Convert.ToByte(negate));
```

Comment: This is not elegant at all. I would reject this in a code review. Elegant code should tell you at first glance what is going on. The `amount *= Math.Sign(0.5 - Convert.ToByte(negate));` is nowhere elegant. It almost obfuscates the problem.

Comment: That's what I said, isn't it?

Comment: No. I think this is a bad example.

Comment: Read info inside brackets. I wouldn't ever include second example in production code, while the first one is perfectly good.

Comment: I agree, I wouldn't use this either. But thanks for the creative answer!

Answer (score -1):

```
amount *= Math.Pow(-1, Convert.ToInt32(negate))
```

This is under the assumption that typecasting a boolean in C# will yield a 0 on false, and a 1 for true.  I however don't think this is elegant as it is an obfuscation.

edit: converted to an int

Comment: This will not compile in strongly-typed C#.